# Past perfect/past perfect continuous or simply past simple(the use of past tenses)

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, past-perfect-continuous

What past tense should I use?

- *Past perfect* :"I **had gone** in for dancing for 3 years before I went in for swimming".
- *Past perfect continuous*:"I **had been going** in for dancing for 3 years before I went in for swimming".
- *Past simple* :"I **went** in for dancing for 3 years before I went in for swimming".

*I want to use this sentence to talk about my past experience*

Comment: I think any of them is acceptable. The "went in for" form is a little, um, not what peopel would say. Maybe attended classes or went to lessons or something?

Comment: This phrase is unusual to my American ears: "I went in for..."